# IOS: Hiding views with animation on click

Tags: ios5, uiviewanimation

I want to hide some views with animation in my app on click similar to Grafio app as shown in image below. Could you please give me some direction to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

make two triangular shaped images first for up direction and another for down direction say up.png and down.png

then set both images for different control states like....

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

now in `IBAction` of that button write...

```
- (IBAction)onEnterQtySaveClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (button.selected)
    {
        // move up the menuView
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            [self.menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        // move down the menuView
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            [self.menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 50)];
        }];
    }

    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

Hope you will like this and it will solve your and many more's problem